# The usage of "against" vs. "on"

Tags: prepositions

Consider the definitions of [against](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/against) in Merriam-Webster:

> She was resting her head **against** the side of the chair.
>
> I accidentally knocked my head **against** the shelf.
>
> She accidentally brushed **against** him as she walked by.
>
> Profits are up this year **against** last year.

Can I use **on** instead in these examples and make no difference in meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Against** and **on** are commonly used interchangeably. I'll talk you through each one to make sure you understand the difference, in general **against** is used to mean **on the side of** rather than from any direction.

> She was resting her head **against** the side of the chair. 
>   I accidentally knocked my head **against** the shelf.

**On** and **against** are both fine here.

> She accidentally brushed **against** him as she walked by.

In this context, if you replace with "on" it doesn't make sense. Brushed against someone is the act of physically touching them as you walk past, if you replace with "on" it almost means to be on top of them in some way.

> Profits are up this year against last year.

This sentence doesn't really make sense. Should be "Profits are up this year since last year" or even better "Profits are up compared to last year". The reason is that in this context **against** is usually used in a competing sense like: "England are playing football against Spain this weekend". Profits can't compete with each other.

Comment: The dictionary lists the last example as legit. What do you make of that? @Tristan

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the definition for ["on"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on?showCookiePolicy=true) in Collins:

- She was resting her head on the side of the chair. `yes - sense 1`
- I accidentally knocked my head on the shelf. `yes - sense 1`
- She accidentally brushed on him as she walked by. `see below`
- Profits are up this year on last year. `yes - sense 14`

Although it's *technically allowed*, it isn't idiomatic, at least not to me (Australian English: Sydney). It fits with **sense 21**, but it's at least questionable. I would recommend that you *avoid* using *on* in that particular frame, since most instances of *on* immediately following a verb are idiomatic.

Comment: I would think in #2 "on" implies hitting on the rim of the shelf while "against" implies hitting on the surface underneath, right?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng not really - on: `in contact or connection with the surface of`, and [against](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/against?showCookiePolicy=true): `coming in contact with`

Comment: US usage would likewise reject *brushed on*, and would probably also reject *on last year*, although we do employ the phrase *year-on-year*. ***Over** last year* would be preferred to both.

Comment: @StoneyB yep. [Collins' US entry for 'on'](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/on?showCookiePolicy=true) doesn't have that sense, but sense 18 `coming after` seems to do the trick. Only seems to work with the bare noun, though.

Comment: An adjective that 'raises' the sense of the iteration works: *insult on humiliating insult*.

Comment: What does "marched on the city" mean? I don't think it's the same as "marched through the city". Is it only for BrE?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Hmm. That particular example, it _does_ seem to have additional meaning, but I have a feeling that it's _axiological_ rather than _epistemological_ meaning - that is, ethically/emotionally loaded. It does lose something if replaced with _marched_, but not knowledge-based... I think it loses some kind of invoked Attitude.